# HTML form input to change CSS font color

Tags: javascript, css, forms

I am trying to use an HTML form to submit a color value.

```
<form>
Font color:<br>
    <input type="color" name="colorInput">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I then want to have the color value to replace another value for font color in CSS:

```
textarea {color: #fff;}
```

I'm new and have little experience with coding.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```css
textarea {color: #fff;}
```

```html
<form>
Font color:<br>
    <input type="color" name="colorInput">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="return false"  onclick="document.getElementById('ss').style.color=colorInput.value; console.log(colorInput.value)">
</form>


<textarea id="ss"rows="10" cols="30">test</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried the code, and it worked. However, the page refreshes when I press 'Submit'. Is there any way around this? Thank you again!

Comment: @RomeroSomero Ok you can use event.preventDefault(); or return false to not refresh page. I've edited it.

Comment: I used event.preventDefault() and it worked! Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: How to get the fiddle link?